# Formatting dates with moment JS to match

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, date-formatting, flatpickr

I am using a third party API along with [Moment JS](https://momentjs.com/) for some date formatting in Javascript.

The third party API groups some data/results with an `epoch` date in milliseconds, such as:

```
1559260800000
```

**This equates to**:
GMT: Friday, 31 May 2019 00:00:00
Your time zone: Friday, 31 May 2019 01:00:00 GMT+01:00 DST
Relative: In 15 days

We are using a [Flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/) calendar for date selection. When a date is selected it returns the selected date in the local date format such as:

```
Fri May 31 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
```

If I use moment to convert that I get the following:

```
var epoch = moment.utc(dayElem.dateObj).valueOf();
```

```
1559257200000
```

**This equates to:**
GMT: Thursday, 30 May 2019 23:00:00
Your time zone: Friday, 31 May 2019 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 DST
Relative: In 15 days

I understand the issue relates to the local timezone and the first being GMT 00:00:00 and second being GMT 00:01:00 but I am unsure how to resolve it.

Furthermore, later dates in the year such as December when we are outside of BST the dates are GMT so I need this to work then too.

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  You say you understand it relates to local timezones, so what sort of resolution are you looking for?  e.g. what's the required behaviour you're after that you're not getting now?

Comment: The two epoch strings need to match. Maybe I take the date from the calendar and ignore time, set timezone to gmt at 00:00:00 then generate it. But ultimately the aim is to get two matching epochs. So the first one is the correct one

Comment: Do you mean you need format selected dates as an epoch value in the Third Party API timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your date picker is producing `Date` objects in terms of local time, but you actually desire them to be in terms of UTC, then you can do the following:

```
var timestamp = moment(dayElem.dateObj).utc(true).valueOf();
```

Passing `true` to the `utc` function will tell it to keep the date and time value and shift the offset, with the trade-off of picking a different moment in time.  In your case, that seems like what you need.

Also, [Please don't call it Epoch Time](https://codeofmatt.com/please-dont-call-it-epoch-time/). :)

Comment: Thanks @Matt, I'll go easy with Epoch wording in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the dates in the date picker to be converted to timestamps representing *midnight in UTC timezone* on the selected date.

Does this do what you want?

```
new Date(moment(dayElem.dateObj).toISOString(true).slice(0, 10)).valueOf()
```

Alternatively, you can use standard `Date` methods and avoid `moment` entirely:

```
var dateObj = dayElem.dateObj;
var utcMidnight = Date.UTC(dateObj.getFullYear(), dateObj.getMonth(), dateObj.getDate());
```